# TinyMCE add lines in <pre> area

Tags: tinymce

I use TinyMCE Editor with codehighlighting plugin in GAE app (python)
When I save my form TinyMCE add a line into [pre] area. If I return in editing and save the form, 
TinyMCE add new blank lines into block.
Sample:
First one:

```
def getTags(cls):
  tag = Tag()
  return ProcessTag.getTags()
```

Second time:

```
def getTags(cls):

  tag = Tag()

  return ProcessTag.getTags()
```

Third time:

```
def getTags(cls):



  tag = Tag()



  return ProcessTag.getTags()
```

How can I resolve?